# Using a button to do the viewPager sliding

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-viewpager

I have a viewPager that shows some images and texts that is taken from a JSON using AsyncTask. My viewPager is working perfectly as it should. But now i need a button to slide the Pages. So when i click that button it should move into the next page just like when we slide the page and it moves to the next page.SO basically i need to move into the next page without sliding but by clicking a button. How can i do this.

NOTE: I already can slide the pages and move into next page.

Following is my fragment class that has the viewPager

```
public class HomeViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private Activity activity;
    private int i = 0;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private Home home;
    private Home now_showing;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;
    private HorizontalListView horizontalListView;
    private LazyAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private ViewPageAdapter adapter1;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_view_fragment, container,
                false);

        horizontalListView = (HorizontalListView) view.findViewById(R.id.horizontal_listview);

        pager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.home_nowshowing); 

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeViewFragment.this.getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Home Page. Please Wait.");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);



        activity = this.getActivity();

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity);


        new BackGround().execute();
        return view;
    }

        public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                home = JSONServices.getHomeListContent();
                now_showing = JSONServices.getHomeListContent();  

                return null;
            } 

            @Override
            /* check again */
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                commonVariable.setHomeListContent(home);
                commonVariable.setHomeListContent(now_showing);

                adapter = new LazyAdapter(home.getHome(), activity,Element.HORIZONTAL_MENU.getType());
                adapter1 = new ViewPageAdapter(home.getNowShowing(),Element.NOW_SHOWING.getType(), activity);


                horizontalListView.setAdapter(adapter);
                pager.setAdapter(adapter1); 

                dialog.dismiss();

                super.onPostExecute(result);

            }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                dialog.show();
                super.onPreExecute();

                }
    }
}
```

layout where i declared the viewpager

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/home_nowshowing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inAnimation="@anim/fade_in_slider"
            android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out_slider" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:background="@drawable/frame_background"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.fortuna.cinemalk.customwidgets.HorizontalListView
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_listview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

layout that uses the viewpager layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:padding="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="380dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/grey" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="245dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/app" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/nowplayingButton"
            android:layout_width="212dp"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/nowshowing_button" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nowplay_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the following method in onClick of button

```
pager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber);
```

OR

```
pager.setCurrentItem(pageNumber, isSmoothScroll;)
```